# Shaking when stopping

Tags: brake-calipers

I changed the rotors and brake pads and my car still shakes. They told me it was the lower control arm, I changed it and it still shakes. I'm starting to think it's the caliper. How or what do I need to do to check that? Do anyone have any idea?

Comment: Describe the shaking please. :)

Comment: Who did the work and were the new brakes bedded properly?

Answer (score 1):

Shaking can be due to a number of things:

- **suspension:** inspect your front suspension for loose or worn out components. Lift the car up in the air and see if you can tilt your wheels up and down by hand. Also, do the knee test to make sure your struts and shocks aren't worn out. In extreme cases, they can cause shaking.
- **hubs:** worn out hubs can cause vibration, although you would first notice it while steering, not braking.
- **unbalanced wheel:** make sure your wheels are properly balanced.
- **brakes:** most commonly, shaking while stopping is a brake related issue. Usually, it's an uneven surface on the rotor or the pads aren't seated properly, or the hardware holding the pads is bent or worn out. I've never seen a caliper cause vibration, but you can check your calipers by raising the car, taking your front wheels off, spinning your rotors by hand and asking somebody to step on the brake, see what happens. Watch your fingers though.